# Read from an RDS file with a sql statement

Tags: r

I'll start by saying I am a beginner in R and am taking a data analysis course.
We were given a very large RDS file (~6mil obs.) to read from and perform calculations. We were told to use readRDS and as you can imagine, this takes forever to read. I only need a subset of the data, which in the past I've used read.csv.sql to limit what I actually read into the program. Is there a way to limit what I read in using readRDS or is there a better way to do this? 
Here's the header of the RDS

```
##     fips      SCC Pollutant Emissions  type year
## 4  09001 10100401  PM25-PRI    15.714 POINT 1999
## 8  09001 10100404  PM25-PRI   234.178 POINT 1999
## 12 09001 10100501  PM25-PRI     0.128 POINT 1999
## 16 09001 10200401  PM25-PRI     2.036 POINT 1999
## 20 09001 10200504  PM25-PRI     0.388 POINT 1999
## 24 09001 10200602  PM25-PRI     1.490 POINT 1999
```

I only need rows where fips == "24510"

Here is the full script:

```
NEI <- readRDS("summarySCC_PM25.rds")
SCC <- readRDS("Source_Classification_Code.rds")

# Aggregate data for just Baltimore
city <- subset(NEI, fips == "24510")
totalPM <- tapply(city$Emissions, city$year, sum)
png(filename='plot2.png')
#Plot data
barplot(totalPM, main=expression('Total Emission of PM for Baltimore'[2.5]),
        xlab='Year', ylab=expression(paste('PM', ''[2.5], ' in Kilotons')))

dev.off()
```

Comment: Exactly how long is `readRDS` taking for you? I created a `data.frame` of ~6 million rows with the same structure as shown above, saved it with `saveRDS`, and read it back in using `readRDS` - which took roughly 6.5 seconds.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I need to switch computers. The whole script (about 8 lines, the sort function and tapply to aggregate ) takes about 6 min

Comment: You should post your entire script then, as the issue is most likely not with `readRDS`.

Comment: I edited the initial question to include all of the code, thanks!